# find minimum cost for hard drive change (Dynamic programming)

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given the prices of different models of hard disks in the next few months, your job is to determine the minimum cost of maintaining the backup disks in the same period of time.

**Assumptions:**

1. User must only buy a new backup hard disk and sell the old one on the first day of a month.
2. He has no backup disk to sell on the first day of the first month. So he needs to buy a new backup disk on the first day of the first month, without selling.
3. The amount he will get by selling a hard disk is exactly $100 less than the current price of a new hard disk of the same model at the selling time.
4. The price of same model hard disks never goes up versus months, and always remains expensive than $100.

   **Input will contain no of brands available "B" followed by no. of months "M". Next line will take brand names and their prices over next months for all "B". You can choose brand names of length 3-10**

*Sample input*

```
    2 4
    Brand1 4000 3600 3500 3400
    Brand2 3500 3500 3200 3000
```

What will be the desired output? I am figuring it to be 3500 but correct answer is  **3400**

Here is my recursive implementation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>


 int min(int p,int q){return p<q?p:q;}
 int t[2][4]={  {4000, 3600, 3500, 3400},
                {3500 ,3500, 3200, 3000}   };



int b=2;
int m=4;


int min_v(int n){
    int i;
    int mint=INT_MAX;
    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
        mint=min(mint,t[i][n]);

    return mint;
}


int min_cost(int b,int m,int sp,int month){

    int i,mint;
    mint=9999;
   
    if(m==month-1){
        printf("MM%d\n",min_v(m)-sp);
        return min_v(m)-sp;
    }
    

    for(i=0;i<=b-1;i++){
        mint=min(mint,t[i][m]-sp+min_cost(b,m+1,t[i][m+1]-100,month));
    }

    return mint;
}


int main(){

    printf("Min cost for backup is  %d",min_cost(b,0,0,m));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @adriano i have solved it but not getting the right answer as i was solving a problem on codechef. Could you please elaborate how can i show SERIOUS attempt? I will definitely improve

Comment: @adriano repetti Kindly push this question for answering. I assure you that i have tried a lot but didn't arrive to the solution. Though the way i have posted may seem fishy but really i am also as passionate as you as net and clean web..Rest is up to you because you have reputation to go with your mind..Thanks

Comment: I retracted my close vote and my downvote, I can't "push" this question to be answered, it depends on readers' interest. May I suggest something? Try to _improve_ your question. Make your code more readable: removing useless comments and adding proper ones, changing variables name to something meaningful and trying to explain your algorithm. IMO it'll be easier for readers if they have a good starting point to improve. Also FAQ here on SO includes many nice "tips" to write a good question (then with bigger chances to have a good answer).

Comment: It's 3400. Buy B for 3500, then on M2 sell B for 3400 and buy A for 3600 (lose 200), then on M4 sell A for 3300 and buy B for 3000 (gain 300).

Comment: @n.m where is M3 purchase..User has to change disk every month. he has to sell and purchase disk every month except first month(oviously he can't sell until he purchases one

Comment: "has to change disk every month" who says so and where?

Comment: @n.m Go through assumption 1

Comment: It does not say what the user must do. It says what the user can do. The word "only" implies a restriction. IOW the user cannot sell or buy in the middle of the month.

Comment: Ok! Now user must do. I have edited the same. Thanks

Comment: If you can't solve the problem by hand for a trivial example you won't be able to write code to solve it for you.

Comment: @towell Would you please help me in arriving the solution rather judging others?

Comment: @n.m Thanks for your reply.. As i got different assumption and solved the same(when user must buy and sell). Thanks for pointing out. Kindly check my recursive solution with assumption that "user must sell or purchase". Thanks